# some import in the project get error separated by newlines or semicolons

Tags: django, import, django-import-export, django-errors

so i have many import in django project. suddenly, the import got red mark (like error sign) but i don't change anything. can someone fix it so it's not detect as error?
i want to fix the error, so the color code can be appear again
[image: like this]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried closing and opening VS Code?

Comment: already but still same @JDODER i was restart laptop too

Comment: If you are using VS Code, maybe you might have installed some extensions that could be causing the problem, so you could try uninstalling your extensions?

Comment: how to check what all i have extensions? @JDODER

Comment: If you use VS Code, go to the left sidebar and click the extension icon. It will show you a list of your extensions.